# How can I conditionally create splunk field aliases?

Tags: splunk

I'm trying to combine info from two different logs into a single query, but I'm not sure how, or if, I can do it. Essentially I want to do this:

```
LOG 1:
<client=foo userId=1234 version=10>
<client=foo userId=5432 version=8>
<client=bar userId=4567 version=4>

LOG 2:
fooid=1234 speed=500
fooid=5432 speed=300
```

What I'm trying to do is gather statistics on the speed of all users who's version == 10.

From what I've read, if I make an alias of userId == fooid, this might be possible by saying something like this:

```
fooid=* AND version=10
```

However, I still have the problem that not all userIds are fooids. So I would like to be able to create a fooid field alias in Log 1, but only if the client=foo. Is this possible, and if so, how can I do it?

Also, if there's some other way to perform this search it would be greatly appreciatied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you bringing in these logs into the same index or do you have them going to separate indexes?  You should be able to do something like index=FOO OR index=FOO2 | search fooid=* AND version=10 if your are bringing into separate indexes.

There is a search cheat sheet on our developer site (http://dev.splunk.com) - http://dev.splunk.com/web_assets/developers/pdf/splunk_reference.pdf

and the search language reference guide can help as well:  http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/WhatsInThisManual

Comment: Right now the plan is to bring them in to the same index. However, if putting them into different indexes would allow me to "join" log messages I could separate them. If they were in the same index, would this work instead:

`index=FOO (sourcetype=LOG1 OR sourcetype=LOG2) | search fooid=* AND version=10`

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
index=FOO (sourcetype=LOG1 client=foo version=10) OR (sourcetype=LOG2) 
| eval user=coalesce(fooid,userid) 
| stats avg(speed) by user
```

The coalesce eval says "user is fooid if it exists, otherwise user is userid".  Other than that, I've just put the appropriate search in to just grab the data you want and a simple stats.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the answers on here are on a good track (especially @[Adrian Hall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1313441/adrian-hall)'s [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29243199/4418) to use [`eval ... coalesce()`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/ConditionalFunctions#coalesce.28.26lt.3Bvalues.29)

But this is simpler:

```
(index=ndx1 sourcetype=srctp userId=* client=* version=*) OR (index=ndx2 sourcetype=srctp2 fooid=* speed=*)
| rename fooid as userId
| stats values(client) as client values(version) as version values(speed) as speed by userId
| where isnotnull(version) AND isnotnull(client) AND isnotnull(speed)
```

You have to combine the different logs before looking for commonalities - one way is with [`join`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/join), but it's *usually* not the right choice - especially when you can leverage [`stats`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/stats) to your advantage :)

Depending on your time frame, using [`fields`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/fields) to drop the raw event (`_raw`) and keep only what you plan to use is likely to be notably faster, too (even if it's not *faster*, it will return a **lot** less data, meaning you won't bump against any user quotas as quickly):

```
(index=ndx1 sourcetype=srctp userId=* client=* version=*) OR (index=ndx2 sourcetype=srctp2 fooid=* speed=*)
| fields - _raw
| fields fooid userId client version speed
| rename fooid as userId
| stats values(client) as client values(version) as version values(speed) as speed by userId
| where isnotnull(version) AND isnotnull(client) AND isnotnull(speed)
```

Lastly, if you have access to the sourcetype's definitional app, you can add `FIELDALIAS` lines in [`props.conf`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Admin/Propsconf#props.conf.example) like this:

```
[srctp1]
FIELDALIAS-userId = userId as fooid

[srctp2]
FIELDALIAS-fooid = fooid AS userId
```

Which would then allow you to just do this in your search (parentheses for clarity):

```
((index=ndx1 sourcetype=srctp client=* version=*) OR (index=ndx2 sourcetype=srctp2 speed=*)) userId=*
| fields - _raw
| fields userId client version speed
| stats values(client) as client values(version) as version values(speed) as speed by userId
| where isnotnull(version) AND isnotnull(client) AND isnotnull(speed)
```

Answer (score -1):

Do this at search time like this:

`index=FOO OR index=FOO2 | eval mergedID=if(isnotnull(fooid),fooid,userId) | transaction mergedID | stats min(speed) max(speed) avg(speed) by version`